# Need ability to get extra attributes for DJIMediaFile: QuickShot type(if taken video with it), timelapse series, AEB series

Tags: dji-sdk

Hi DJI SDK developer team. My team and I requested a few times such needed information. 
Please help us and include following meta to next SDK builds:

We need to know series of shots for Timelapse shooting, AEB shooting. So in our grid of taken photos, we can group them as one item.
Also, we want to show Rocket, Helix, Boomerang, Asteroid, etc. icons on our files grid too.

P.S. Now we already have DJI Pro membership, but the button for support doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. I've send this to the proper channel.

The best way to send feature requests or report issues is to email dev@dji.com or use the support through the User Center in [developer.dji.com](http://developer.dji.com).

Comment: Where can I check the status of this feature request?